# NSTableView - how to get automatic and manual sorting working together?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, sorting, nstableview

I have a `NSTableView` in `MyViewController` and have an array controller bound to it. I want to be able to sort it by clicking the table column headers and it should also auto-sort. So for auto-sort I set the Sort Descriptors binding of my array controller in IB as following:

```
Bind to: MyViewController
Model Key Path: customSortDescriptors
```

In the MyViewController class I've added:

```
var customSortDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor] {
    let sd = NSSortDescriptor(key: "string", ascending: true, selector: "localizedStandardCompare:");
    return [sd]
}
```

And for the related table column in IB I've set:

```
Sort Key: string
Selector: caseInsensitiveCompare:
```

This works OK until I click on the table column header upon where I get an error thrown:

> Error setting value for key path customSortDescriptors of object
>   NSAutounbinder: 0x60000005e060 - a nonretaining proxy for
>   MyApp.MyViewController: 0x6000000e6600 (from bound object
>   NSArrayController: 0x6000001c0b40[entity: GeneratedData, number of
>   selected objects: 0]): [MyApp.MyViewController 0x6000000e6600
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key customSortDescriptors.

I'm not sure why I get this error. Can somebody tell me what is wrong? Why would MyViewController not be key value coding-compliant? Aren't NSViews and NSViewControllers compliant by default?

Besides that the sorting works without problems but I get the error thrown in Xcode and want to eliminate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be damned but the reason for the error is obviously that the property is read-only. So adding a setter, or better yet, change the code to simply:

```
var customSortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "string", ascending: true, selector: "localizedStandardCompare:")];
```

fixed the error and both, automatic and manual sorting works.

Comment: More recently, it seems that `var` throws the same error - we have to use `@objc dynamic var` instead.